# Mantaflow liquid domain with animation nodes: do particles change index?

Tags: particles, animation-nodes, mantaflow

Ok, I wanted to answer [how to make an object flow along with a mantaflow simulation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265571/how-to-make-an-object-flow-along-with-mantaflow-simulation) and I thought hey, cool idea: just use animation nodes.

So I created this animation node setup:

[image: animation node setup]

but the result was:

[image: unexpected flow]

I don't know whether you can see it because the gif result isn't that great, but it is obvious that the location "jumps" around crazy as hell so it looks like the particle system (or better: the particles data) which come from the AN aren't keeping their index. Am I missing something or is this how it is supposed to be?

Comment: Animation Nodes? Probably another reminder to me that I'm still pretty inexperienced at Blender. Anyways, what the logical solution would have been was to make the sphere a rigid body and in some way make the sphere be affected by the particles of the fluid and simultaneously be a collision object (which I gues you're trying to do and to what I think blender should do that automatically, the whole physics system should be interlinked) and also add the domain as a pasive rigid body (since I think the rigid body will be using its base mesh if we set it to base)